# Optimal algorithm for choosing similarly-sized readings

Tags: algorithm, word-wrap, bin-packing

Say you have a book with a hundred chapters and you want to read it in seven sessions. The dumbest way to do this is to divide it into the same number of chapters per session, but what if the chapters vary wildly in length and you want your reading sessions to be as evenly divided as possible? Or, instead of a certain number of readings, what if you want to optimize for a certain word count or length of time (average wpm reading speed is 200, so say you wanted to optimize for 3,000 words or 15 minutes per reading session)?

I’m not looking for code samples since I’m assuming this problem is already solved but I’m having trouble finding the abstracted form/name of this kind of algorithm. It’s similar to bin-packing algorithms but with the added constraint that you can’t sort the items into bins out of sequence (you don’t want to read the book out of order; you’ll spoil the ending!). If you can help me figure out the kind of algorithm I’m looking for I’m happy to study on my own to find a specific form of it (or write my own) that will work for my specific context. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds similar to the “minimum raggedness” problem in line breaking.

Comment: [minimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax)?

Comment: As long as you can determine where you are in the boook so you can work out how many words are in each chapter, you could certainly break it into 15 minute reading blocks  by breaking it into 300 word chunks. For example with amazon kindle it'll give you an indication of how far into the book you are based on % done. So 7 sessions would be bout 14% of the book each session. If you only know what chapter you are on, there isn't much you can do.

Comment: @Sneftel, your comment pointed me in exactly the right direction. I was able to abstract from creating equal-length lines from words in a paragraph (breaking on spaces between the words) to creating equal-length readings from chapters in a book (breaking on chapter breaks) and implement my own version of the minimum raggedness algorithm that solved my problem perfectly. I never would've come up with that connection on my own. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to hear it :-)